# How would you display these two div elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to display two div elements correctly right next to each other and I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about this.
[Here you can see what it looks like live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veFmB.jpg)

And this would be the code:

**This is the first element shown in the picture, the second div has this exact same code, only the text/image changes.**

```
<main class="page"><h1>Downloads</h1>
       <div class="album1">
           <div class="image">
           <img src="IMAGES/led-zeppelin-iii-1555363141.jpg" alt="album1">
           </div>
           <div class="text">
           <h2>Led Zeppelin III</h2>
       <ol>
           <li><a href="#">Immigrant Song</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Celebration Day</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Since I've been Loving You</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Out on the Tiles</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Gallows Pole</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tangerine</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">That's the Way</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Bron-Y-Aur Stomp</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hats Off to Roy Harper</a></li>
       </ol>
           </div>
           </div>
```

**And this is what I have for CSS for both main div elements, both are called album1 and album2. The actual text has its own div that applies to both elements.**

```
.album1
{
display: flex;
align-items:flex-start;
padding-bottom: 85px;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.album2
{
display: flex;
float: right;
align-items:flex-start;
padding-bottom: 85px;
}
```

Your help would greatly be appreciated cause this is for my final and the professor isn't any help :(

If you need additional info I will happily provide it, sorry I'm still getting the hang of this.

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with your current layout? What did you expect to happen, what - exactly - do you need your layout to achieve? As you're new to the site, I'd suggest reading the guidelines on "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*," also you may benefit from taking the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to display the albums side by side.
To achieve that you can place both the albums in a parent container (Example: classname = albums) and give it a `display:flex`.

Also you can use `justify-content: space-between;` to place it in two ends. `float: right;` is not required.

```css
.albums {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.album1
{
display: flex;
align-items:flex-start;
padding-bottom: 85px;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.album2
{
display: flex;
align-items:flex-start;
padding-bottom: 85px;
}
```

```html
<main class="page"><h1>Downloads</h1>
       <div class="albums">
            <div class="album1">
               <div class="image">
               ASDASD
               </div>
               <div class="text">
                     <h2>Led Zeppelin III</h2>
                     <ol>
                         <li><a href="#">Immigrant Song</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Celebration Day</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Since I've been Loving You</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Out on the Tiles</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Gallows Pole</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Tangerine</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">That's the Way</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Bron-Y-Aur Stomp</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Hats Off to Roy Harper</a></li>
                     </ol>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="album1">
             <div class="image">
             ASDASD
             </div>
             <div class="text">
                   <h2>Led Zeppelin III</h2>
                   <ol>
                       <li><a href="#">Immigrant Song</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Celebration Day</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Since I've been Loving You</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Out on the Tiles</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Gallows Pole</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Tangerine</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">That's the Way</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Bron-Y-Aur Stomp</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Hats Off to Roy Harper</a></li>
                   </ol>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent div for both div album1 and album2,

then make it display:flex , so album1 and album2 will align next to each other.

```css
.albumgroup { display:flex; }
.album1 { //your css here}
.album2 { //your css here}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="albumgroup">
        <div class="album1">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="IMAGES/led-zeppelin-iii-1555363141.jpg" alt="album1">
            </div>
    
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Led Zeppelin III</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="#">Immigrant Song</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Celebration Day</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Since I've been Loving You</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Out on the Tiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallows Pole</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tangerine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">That's the Way</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bron-Y-Aur Stomp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hats Off to Roy Harper</a></li>
                </ol>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="album2">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="IMAGES/led-zeppelin-iii-1555363141.jpg" alt="album2">
            </div>
    
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Led Zeppelin IV</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="#">Immigrant Song</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Celebration Day</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Since I've been Loving You</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Out on the Tiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallows Pole</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tangerine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">That's the Way</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bron-Y-Aur Stomp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hats Off to Roy Harper</a></li>
                </ol>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you a pretty simple example on how to do this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="album1">
            <h1>Album1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="album2">
            <h1>Album2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.album1 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 50vw;
}

.album2 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 50vw;
}
```

ANd the **result** will be like this:
[image]

Then, inside your *album1* and *album2*, put everything you want.